# Tabbars stacking on top of each other

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Currently I have a TabBarController with some tabs in it. However if I try to open another TabBarController with tabs as a popup (code below), the tabbars just stack. I have tried using TabBarcontroller?.tabbar.ishidden = false. But it just hides the previous tabbar, without removing the spacing. Like the new tabbar is above the hidden space (constraints still there). I just want it to popup overtop of the previous controller. Also in case you are wondering, I am opening the VC from one of the First Tabbar controllers. FYI, the tabbar backgrounds are clear so thats why they look like that.

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
"MyTabBarController") as! MyTabBarController
self.addChild(vc)
vc.view.frame = self.view.frame
self.view.addSubview(vc.view)
vc.didMove(toParent: self)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to replace the original tab bar controller with your new tab bar controller, or present "as a popup"?

Comment: Present it as a popup, while removing the bottom tabbar

Comment: You may want to add more tabs if the user is in any of a list of tabs (edit: oh, not swiftui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding your `MyTabBarController` as a child view, i.e. embed this controller in the existing one (self).
The reason the previous TabBar (or its spacing) is still there is, that `self` isn't the previous TabBarController but one of the embedded tabs. The frame of these tab controllers do not include the TabBars frame.
E.g. if the TabBarVCs frame is (0, 0, 320, 640) and the TabBars frame is (0, 600, 320, 40), then the tab controllers frames are (0, 0, 320, 600).

---

To show your `MyTabBarController` as a popup, i.e. covering your current vc without modifying it's views, just present the new vc like this:

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyTabBarController") as! MyTabBarController   
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```